# Error when using New-Item / md / mkdir

Tags: powershell

I've currently got a script that:

1. Loops through some files
2. Checks the name of the file
3. If there is no directory for the file it will create one
4. Moves the file into the directory

The moving logic works fine. However if a directory does not exist I am given this error (the path is valid, except it does not exist)

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Directory\FileName : The term 'C:\Users\User\Documents\
Directory\FileName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
C:\Users\User\Documents\Directory\FileName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\User\Documents\Directory\FileName) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The curious part is that it does actually create the folder - however it crashes my script.

Here's the problem part of the script

```
function CanCreate($dir) {
    return !(Test-Path $dir)
}

if (CanCreate($fullDestinationPath)) {
    New-Item $fullDestinationPath -ItemType Directory
}
```

`md`/`mkdir` behave differently to `New-Item` in that they do crash the script, however `New-Item` prints the error and continues (script seems to finish its job).

**Edit:**

The issue seems to stem from the fact that I am calling the script from another script.

```
$ScriptPath = "C:\Powershell Scripts\script.ps1"
& $ScriptPath | Invoke-Expression
```

Comment: show the rest of the script

Comment: Your error message suggests a problem with your code, not with the `New-Item`CmdLet itself. You need to share more of your code.

Comment: It seems to me that you did not define a path at the beginning of your script. Try: $path = 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Directory\FileName'

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` is [considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/), and the way you're using it is simply asking for trouble. Don't *EVER* do things like `& some.ps1 | Invoke-Expression`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was with the fact that I was using `| Invoke-Expression` to trigger the script.

Simply calling `& $ScriptPath`, omitting the `| Invoke-Expression`, was enough to trigger the script.

Thanks everyone.